# How to convert scapy object to a string

Tags: python, scapy

I have an use-case where in i will create a scapy packet on remote server (for automation perse) and need to pass the scapy packet to the respective device where i need to trigger actual traffic.

```
For eg:
        ip_layer = IP(src='x.x.x.x', dst='y.y.y.y')
        icmp_layer = ICMP(type=3, code=1)
        my_pkt = ip_layer/icmp_layer
```

How do i pass this scapy object created (my_pkt) an use it to send on other device
Is there a way i can convert the whole scapy object to string ,and use just send(scapy_str) on rmeote server.
From scapy docs i see export_objects,import_objects present.But in turn export_objects just prints it instead of returning the value.\
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a packet to bytes using

```
bytes(my_pkt)
```

A bytes string is what is used in networking

Comment: This bytes string can directly be fed as input to the send/sendp method?